# Not able to enter windows phone dashboard at windows development

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have built a windows phone App and I want to upload it. However, after signing in (with my windows account) and clicking on "Windows phone store" I just get redirected at the same page!  I tried to create another account but that didn't help either. I deleted cookies, history,... and even tried with another browser but again nothing. I must also mention that I do not get any message after being redirected.
Could it be that they could have a issue. Can anyone try to access the dashboard? 
Any suggestion on what could the problem be are welcome.

This is the linking which I am referring to:    https://dev.windows.com/en-us/dashboard

Comment: Isn't it asking for informations about Windows 8.1 applications?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Just redirection. I have never experienced such a thing in my life by a professional website.

Comment: I just have to add that "Windows store" button lead's me towards the dashboard whereas the "Windows phone store" does still not!

Comment: It seems that newly created accounts can not enter the windows phone store altough already created accounts can!( I have spoken to some people and they are having a issue as well). Hope that MS will fix that soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft removed the problem, in other words newly created accounts can enter the "Windows phone store" dashboard!